cPanel Error /20/bin/npm: line 35: /opt/alt/alt-nodejs20/root/usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
I currently trying to deploy my nodejs project to cPanel. I have followed every steps to upload it and I am having problem when run NPM Install. I always got this error
Error
/nodevenv/myprojecttest1/20/bin/npm: line 35: /opt/alt/alt-nodejs20/root/usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory


I am not sure what wrong have I done, but here is the code for my files
app.js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const viewRouter = require('./routes/main');

const app = express();
//app.use(express.json()); 

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

// Static File
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Middleware
app.use('/', viewRouter);

app.get('/overview', (req, res) =>{
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
    res.render('test3');
});

app.use((req,res) => {
    const viewData = {
        pageTitle: 'Page Not Found Bro'
    };
    res.status(404).render('404', viewData);
});



module.exports = app;

server.js
const app = require('./app');

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});

package.json
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "coolkid",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.10",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}

and if I run script this error will pops out
returncode: 127
stdout:

stderr:
/nodevenv/myprojecttest1/20/bin/npm: line 37: /opt/alt/alt-nodejs20/root/usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory

